# Unexpected error in log when using Thin Server with a simple Rails application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I am pretty new at using the Thin server on my simple rails application. It's working nicely except, that 1 out of 4 times more or less when I go to any page in the app I get this on the browser:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error Content-Type: text/html
Application error

Change this error message for exceptions thrown outside of an action (like in Dispatcher         setups or broken Ruby code) in public/500.html
```

and this in the log:

```
Processing PlansController#index (for 24.61.84.158 at 2012-03-02 17:53:48) [GET]
  Session ID: 3105294042126eab3c6292d3ba224847
  Parameters: {"controller"=>"plans", "action"=>"index"}
Rendering layoutfalseactionlist within layouts/standard
Rendering plans/list
Completed in 0.18974 (5 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.10813 (56%) | DB: 0.03900 (20%) | 200 OK [http://admin.blogbridge.com/]
file /tmp/ruby_sess.5684ebd33a502d9d not readable
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/pstore.rb:100:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi/session/pstore.rb:61:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi/session/pstore.rb:61:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi/session.rb:280:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p357/lib/ruby/1.8/cgi/session.rb:280:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:123:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:123:in `session'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:155:in `stale_session_check!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:110:in `session'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1052:in `assign_shortcuts_without_flash'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:140:in `assign_shortcuts'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:424:in `process_without_filters'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:624:in `process_without_session_management_support'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb:114:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/actionpack-1.13.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:330:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/rails-1.2.3/lib/dispatcher.rb:41:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:89:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:69:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `send'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/thin:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/bin/thin:19
```

Has anyone has seen this before?

Comment: More of a workaround than a solution, but consider using a memcache store for sessions, which has the benefits of being more scalable, faster, and has a good chance of avoiding this issue. Btw, do you have a distributed architecture, or anything special about the filesystem that this is on?

Comment: Thanks.. But no, it's quite a vanilla set up. Linux box at Linode, running Centos. Just experimenting with launching Thin server via Apache virtual domain. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

What sticks out to me is that rails-1.2.3 is in your stack. I believe if you `bundle exec thin` you'll get the correct version of rails, but you can also force this by removing all gems that aren't dependencies of your app.

While rvm is great for development, I'm not convinced it brings much value when installed at a system level, and I've heard lots of people struggling with it on production systems (especially CentOS) in terms of getting the environment correct for whatever user thin is running as. If you're new to rails deployments, consider using something like passenger, and just `sudo gem install` the dependencies.